# calendar control in qt

Tags: qt

I have calendar in Qt. I want when user selects date, 14(Qint32) will be added in it and resultant date should be highlighted on 2nd calendar. Please let me know how can I do that, I'm beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick.

```
QCalendarWidget cal1 = new QCalendarWidget(this);
QCalendarWidget cal2 = new QCalendarWidget(this);

connect(cal1, SIGNAL(clicked(const QDate &)), this, SLOT(changeDate(const QDate &)));

.../...

void MyWidget::changeDate(const QDate &date1) //< declared as a slot in your .h
{
    QDate d2 = date1.addDays(14);
    cal2->setSelectedDate(d2);
}
```